# Adding a My Location Button in google maps on my android app

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm trying to add the my location button in my android application. This is the code I currently have:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    int position;
    String alllatitude,alllongitude,alldirname;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        Intent i=getIntent();

        position=i.getIntExtra("POSITION", 0);

        alllatitude=i.getStringExtra("LATITUDE");
        alllongitude=i.getStringExtra("LONGITUDE");
        alldirname=i.getStringExtra("DIRNAME");
        LatLng TutorialsPoint = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(alllatitude), Double.parseDouble(alllongitude));
        try {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
            googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(TutorialsPoint, 15.0f));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(TutorialsPoint)
                    .title(alldirname));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: use  this `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);` for showing the current location button in google map.

Comment: This might be a dumb question but does the code need to be in a certain line?

Comment: do you want to use the default current location btn or custom btn?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this to display the default location button on the Google Maps V2 API for android.

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 

googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Got it to work! Thanks I just added the line of code under this line:

`try {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Comment: Yes, not any specific line, just after the google map object initialization

Comment: it's not working on mine. Many other features i.e. compass are working but this thing just decided to not show up on the map.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the basic location button, such as the one on the Google Maps app, do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    // Used for finding current location with button
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I get error message of "unfortunately app has stopped" when I try to use the maps option.

Comment: Also getting "map cannot be resolved" when adding this line of code:

`map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);     map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);`

Comment: Got it working!
Thanks to everyone for there quick answers, resolved it just by adding 
`googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);`

UNDER


`{
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

Comment: That's strange, sorry I don't have a solution. I'm glad you managed to get it working though!